# Design do HTML está estranha

Tags: html

Esta é estrutura básica do HTML e estou rodando ela com um live-server, porém, o design na web está estranha. O Some body text está muito longe da borda esquerda, o arquivo css que está no código, é um reset CSS e acabei importando e mesmo assim não houve diferença.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
         href="notesApp/normalize.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        Some body text
    </body>
</html>
```

Na imagem aparece sem a importação, mas não tem problema.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: clica para visualizar o código fonte da página e veja se realmente está importando o normalize pois era para resolver este problema de margem com certeza!

Comment: Testa deixar o <body> em uma unica linha e veja se resolve, mas se possível poste o codigo CSS tbm

Comment: Então, este problema de margem está acontecendo apenas com os textos sem as tags, se eu coloco um header, ou um paragraph, ele fica certo.

Comment: eu acho que o normalize faz isto, mas na dúvida coloca dentro dentro dele body { margin:0; padding:0; }

Comment: Coloquei, e não mudou nada

Comment: Entrei na console e apareceu este erro:                                            Refused to apply style from 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/notesApp/normalize.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Comment: cara seu erro está no seu normalize mesmo, vou postar meu teste aqui com o normalize que eu acabei de baixar. dai vc substitui o seu ok?

Comment: Okay, pelo erro que percebi foi porque começava com comentários o normalize.css, acabei tirando os comentários e mesmo assim. Mas fico  agradecido se você puder enviar

Comment: só copiar e colar o normalize.css

Comment: Abra o console do browser na aba network, recarregue a página, selecione o css em questão e coloca um print para vermos que o está mostrando ali. Pelo seu print, o caminho é sem notesApp/. Deve estar dando 404

Comment: Como faço este print?

Comment: Usei o que o @MatheusMuriel disse, e deu certo, mas eu quero entender o porquê disto

Comment: Porque tem alguma regra de CSS, talvez algum padrão do browser, que está forçando fonte monospaced e espaços preformatados, mostrando todos os espaços em branco do código-fonte html (em vez de fundir tudo num único espaço). Ainda acho que o seu arquivo css não está sendo carregado.

Comment: Então como eu faria para carregar o arquivo CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vagner, você está com problema no seu arquivo normalize.css.

Segue exemplo funcionando pra vc.

normalize.css

```css
/*! normalize.css v8.0.1 | MIT License | github.com/necolas/normalize.css */

/* Document
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * 1. Correct the line height in all browsers.
 * 2. Prevent adjustments of font size after orientation changes in iOS.
 */

html {
  line-height: 1.15; /* 1 */
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 2 */
}

/* Sections
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Remove the margin in all browsers.
 */

body {
  margin: 0;
}

/**
 * Render the `main` element consistently in IE.
 */

main {
  display: block;
}

/**
 * Correct the font size and margin on `h1` elements within `section` and
 * `article` contexts in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.
 */

h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0.67em 0;
}

/* Grouping content
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * 1. Add the correct box sizing in Firefox.
 * 2. Show the overflow in Edge and IE.
 */

hr {
  box-sizing: content-box; /* 1 */
  height: 0; /* 1 */
  overflow: visible; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * 1. Correct the inheritance and scaling of font size in all browsers.
 * 2. Correct the odd `em` font sizing in all browsers.
 */

pre {
  font-family: monospace, monospace; /* 1 */
  font-size: 1em; /* 2 */
}

/* Text-level semantics
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Remove the gray background on active links in IE 10.
 */

a {
  background-color: transparent;
}

/**
 * 1. Remove the bottom border in Chrome 57-
 * 2. Add the correct text decoration in Chrome, Edge, IE, Opera, and Safari.
 */

abbr[title] {
  border-bottom: none; /* 1 */
  text-decoration: underline; /* 2 */
  text-decoration: underline dotted; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Add the correct font weight in Chrome, Edge, and Safari.
 */

b,
strong {
  font-weight: bolder;
}

/**
 * 1. Correct the inheritance and scaling of font size in all browsers.
 * 2. Correct the odd `em` font sizing in all browsers.
 */

code,
kbd,
samp {
  font-family: monospace, monospace; /* 1 */
  font-size: 1em; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Add the correct font size in all browsers.
 */

small {
  font-size: 80%;
}

/**
 * Prevent `sub` and `sup` elements from affecting the line height in
 * all browsers.
 */

sub,
sup {
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

sub {
  bottom: -0.25em;
}

sup {
  top: -0.5em;
}

/* Embedded content
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Remove the border on images inside links in IE 10.
 */

img {
  border-style: none;
}

/* Forms
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * 1. Change the font styles in all browsers.
 * 2. Remove the margin in Firefox and Safari.
 */

button,
input,
optgroup,
select,
textarea {
  font-family: inherit; /* 1 */
  font-size: 100%; /* 1 */
  line-height: 1.15; /* 1 */
  margin: 0; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Show the overflow in IE.
 * 1. Show the overflow in Edge.
 */

button,
input { /* 1 */
  overflow: visible;
}

/**
 * Remove the inheritance of text transform in Edge, Firefox, and IE.
 * 1. Remove the inheritance of text transform in Firefox.
 */

button,
select { /* 1 */
  text-transform: none;
}

/**
 * Correct the inability to style clickable types in iOS and Safari.
 */

button,
[type="button"],
[type="reset"],
[type="submit"] {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
}

/**
 * Remove the inner border and padding in Firefox.
 */

button::-moz-focus-inner,
[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner,
[type="reset"]::-moz-focus-inner,
[type="submit"]::-moz-focus-inner {
  border-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

/**
 * Restore the focus styles unset by the previous rule.
 */

button:-moz-focusring,
[type="button"]:-moz-focusring,
[type="reset"]:-moz-focusring,
[type="submit"]:-moz-focusring {
  outline: 1px dotted ButtonText;
}

/**
 * Correct the padding in Firefox.
 */

fieldset {
  padding: 0.35em 0.75em 0.625em;
}

/**
 * 1. Correct the text wrapping in Edge and IE.
 * 2. Correct the color inheritance from `fieldset` elements in IE.
 * 3. Remove the padding so developers are not caught out when they zero out
 *    `fieldset` elements in all browsers.
 */

legend {
  box-sizing: border-box; /* 1 */
  color: inherit; /* 2 */
  display: table; /* 1 */
  max-width: 100%; /* 1 */
  padding: 0; /* 3 */
  white-space: normal; /* 1 */
}

/**
 * Add the correct vertical alignment in Chrome, Firefox, and Opera.
 */

progress {
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

/**
 * Remove the default vertical scrollbar in IE 10+.
 */

textarea {
  overflow: auto;
}

/**
 * 1. Add the correct box sizing in IE 10.
 * 2. Remove the padding in IE 10.
 */

[type="checkbox"],
[type="radio"] {
  box-sizing: border-box; /* 1 */
  padding: 0; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Correct the cursor style of increment and decrement buttons in Chrome.
 */

[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  height: auto;
}

/**
 * 1. Correct the odd appearance in Chrome and Safari.
 * 2. Correct the outline style in Safari.
 */

[type="search"] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield; /* 1 */
  outline-offset: -2px; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Remove the inner padding in Chrome and Safari on macOS.
 */

[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

/**
 * 1. Correct the inability to style clickable types in iOS and Safari.
 * 2. Change font properties to `inherit` in Safari.
 */

::-webkit-file-upload-button {
  -webkit-appearance: button; /* 1 */
  font: inherit; /* 2 */
}

/* Interactive
   ========================================================================== */

/*
 * Add the correct display in Edge, IE 10+, and Firefox.
 */

details {
  display: block;
}

/*
 * Add the correct display in all browsers.
 */

summary {
  display: list-item;
}

/* Misc
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Add the correct display in IE 10+.
 */

template {
  display: none;
}

/**
 * Add the correct display in IE 10.
 */

[hidden] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="notesApp/normalize.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        Some body text
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Estou com o mesmo erro ainda

Comment: Quando eu tiro o notesApp/ na hora do href, ele não aparece o erro, porém, continua a mesma coisa a parte gráfica

Comment: impossível cara. clica em executar ali encima

Comment: Sim, cliquei em executar e vi que o seu rodou bem certo. O meu ainda está com este problema, e aparece aquele erro que comentei do Refused to apply se eu coloco a pasta no href